# "You have an error in your SQL syntax" error not giving me enough direction, how can I get more specific feedback?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to test out some basic functionality, but I'm stuck on something that I don't think I should be stuck on. My db connection is good and tested in the lines before, but the execution of a simple SQL query returns "Error in the consult..You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''classes'' at line 1"

```
// define query
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'classes'";

# execute the query.
$result = $db_connection->query($query) or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($db_connection));
```

The table name 'classes' isn't a reserved term, and I get the same error if I test against any of the other tables. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Get rid of the quotes around classes. Either use ticks or nothing at all.

Comment: As others have said, your table name is a database object, not a string. It is similar to column names and other objects that actually exist in the database.

Comment: The question is "how can I get more specific feedback?" While the fix is a simple typographical correction, that was not the question. You should dump the query string and copy/paste it into your favorite database application (sequel pro, phpmyadmin). The database itself will provide you the specific feedback you are looking for.

Comment: I copied the SQL from phpMyAdmin, but I assumed the ticks were invalid markings and so replaced them with quotes. The error tells me to check the manual for my version of MySQL, which I did but it's a manual, so with no further diagnostic information from the error message I was unable to solve the problem myself. I alluded to that fact with my stab-in-the-dark of reserved term.

Despite having my specific problem solved, my original desire to have a more robust error message stands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ticks around the "classes" in your query:

```
// define query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `classes`";

# execute the query.
$result = $db_connection->query($query) or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($db_connection));
```

Comment: Wow, that is the first I've ever heard of ticks being used. Thank you!